# Mathematica stops working with no warning/error

Tags: kernel, crash, error-tracking

I have some long computations on my Mathematica notebook.
For some reason they stop and Mathematica gives me no reason as to why. No warning. No erros.

If run the "Initialization Lines" (create variables, etc) and then each long calculation then, sometimes, I am able to perform them. But I cant run the notebook from top to bottom without stopping.

My RAM and CPU dont max out.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wonder how anyone could help. Your question is very general. Perhaps you should ask for tips on debugging to try to find where the problem is?

Comment: If you go to the help menu and select "Why the beep?", does it tell you anything?

Comment: Lou I know, but it is everything it shows me... I don't think the code is the issue because if I run each line separately is runs fine.
@MichaelE2 ""The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation"

Comment: Try placing a single `Quit[]` in the middle of the code. Run it. If it crashes with the above error, move the `Quit[]` half way in between the above chunk of code. Otherwise if it quits before the error is encountered, then move the `Quit[]` to the midpoint of the remaining code. Keep proceeding this way (binary chop) until you narrow down the first line where the error occurs before a quit. Post this line when you find it.

Comment: @flinty I have been having exactly the same issue as Joao since Mathematica 12 came out. It is not any single line of code that is the problem but asking Mathematica to execute more than one cell at the same time, whether by manually selecting n>1 lines or clicking evaluate notebook or run initialization cells. And it is extremely random. Sometimes it happens when I want to evaluate two consecutive lines like `d=3;` `D=4;`. There is no way to consistenly reproduce it, but it happens often. I will have to 24h video my work for you to see. Evaluating each line by hand always works, though.

Comment: It is also extremely efficient at quitting Mathematica. Faster than quitting the kernel/s in any possible way from Mathematica or killing them from the OS (using Ubuntu here). It is instantenous, the moment you press shift-enter, all Matheamtica windows (if more than one was present) close and the memory is instanly freed. I would like to know what internal command does that so I can use it, when I want to quickly stop an evaluation.